# Does Linksys E3200 have a hard limit on wifi connections?

Tags: router

I have a Linksys E3200 in my office, and once in a while it gets crowded what with everybody bringing 3 devices into the office. Sometimes the router would refuse connection through Wifi when there's already a lot of Wifi connections, but LAN connections are always OK. It is running Tomato Shibby. My question is do routers have hard limit on number of Wifi connections? I've been searching on Google and in the manual book but have found no mention of this. Thank you.

Comment: There plausibly is a limit on processing power, which may affect in this way. WiFi may be more "CPU-hungry" than wired connections. Check what kind of processing power the device has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WOW!  I can't believe how easy the issue was with me.  ALTHOUGH I have a Cisco and not a linksys wireless, I'm assuming this capacity is available in the wireless settings found on your wireless router.

1) Check your DHCP is fine and you have more than enough IP's DHCP pool for the number of devices you want to connect.  DHCP is your dynamically assigned IP addresses that your devices are assigned from the router.  Your list may look something like this:

```
- Start Range: 192.168.1.50
- End Range: 192.168.1.254
```

This means that 204 devices can connect.  Ensure you are under the limit in your office.  On Cisco you find this info at: `Networking -> LAN -> IPv4 LAN (Local Area Network)`.  So basically you configure it in your IPv4 Lan network settings in your router.

2) Once you've confirmed your DHCP pool is over the amount of required connections to the router then check your Max Connection pool.  Yep!  Sometimes it's just as easy as this which blew my mind that I was overseeing this part of the configuration process.  In `Wireless -> Basic Settings` you'll see a table of enabled SSID connections to the router.  In mine there are 4 with only one enabled.  At the very end of the table you'll see `Max. Associated Clients` and it was set to some awfully low number "8".  I increased this and now everything works beautifully.  So you'll want to search your SSID enabled connections and make sure your max client number is higher than the number of connected devices.

3) IF in fact you DO exceed the DHCP pool, either you'll want to change your subnet mask settings so you can open up how many IP's are connecting or you'll have to get another router and may need to chain it on different wireless channels.  You'll probably want a tech guy for that because that involves some elbow grease.

Comment: :-/  I'm not at all convinced I deserved a negative vote.

Comment: Don't take it too personally - folks can be unnecessarily harsh with them sometimes. The important thing is that you made a *very good* answer on this question :)

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by the number of available IP address in your subnet. if you only allow 100 connection in the DHCP server, any new device won't be able to connect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked that and the DHCP table was not full.

Comment: How many connections do you need to have before you're unable to connect?